# Convert from vector<IplImage*> to vector<Mat>

Tags: opencv

I was troubling with this operation. I can't get it through. Where am I missing?

```
vector<Mat> blobC;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < blobCFinal.size(); i++)
{
    blobC.at(i) = blobCFinal.at(i);
}
```

where

```
vector<IplImage*> blobCFinal;
```

If I'm not mistaken usual way of converting normal type is like this,

```
IplImage* blobCFinal;
Mat blobC(blobCFinal);
```

Ans: Thanks to @rotating_image, probably this will work

```
vector<Mat> blobC;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < blobCFinal.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat dummy = Mat(blobCFinal[i]);
        blobC.push_back(dummy);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
vector<Mat> blobC;
vector<IplImage*> blobCFinal;

//some processing 

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < blobCFinal.size(); i++)
{
    Mat dummy = Mat(blobCFinal[i]);
    blobC[i] = dummy.clone();
}
```

Comment: Just tested. Some error though. Why vector subscript out of range?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with blobC and blobCFinal?copy the Matrices one by one or what?whats the size of blobCFinal?

Comment: I use cvBlobsLib for finding the blobs but the libs used old C API. Now I have many blobs and I want to convert the stored blobs from blobCFinal to blobC which is in Mat.

Comment: blobC is one object of the blob class or the image containing the blobs?

Comment: blobC should contain the same as blobCFinal whr blocCFinal contains the blobs of an object from an image.

Comment: suppose the image has 5 blobs so what is blobCFinal? is it the image with 5 blobs? or is it the vector of images, each image containing each of the 5 blob only?

Comment: I've updated my answer It works now but I'm not sure it is correct way or not. @rotating_image thank you.